# Bit definition error - IAR Workbench

Tags: iar, stm32f4discovery

I am a beginner with embedded programming and am using the IAR workbench for a project of mine using `STM32F4Discovery`. I am trying to compile an existing code and have a few errors at  a few places regarding the bit definitions like the following:

`Error[Pe020]: identifier "GPIO_PIN_SET" is undefined`

Now, the `GPIO_PIN_SET` is defined in the file `stm32f4xx_gpio_hal.h` and is already included in my project. In order to resolve this issue when I looked up online, I have found [this](https://www.electronicsblog.net/start-with-iar-embedded-workbench-for-atmel-avr-attiny13-led-blink-with-timer-interrupt/) solution. However, I don't have the `System`  tab in the `General Options` in my IAR Workbench. I have a full version of IAR Workbench and am not sure why the `System` tab is missing.

I also tried defining

```
#define ENABLE_BIT_DEFINITIONS
```

as stated in [this](http://supp.iar.com/Support/?note=25083) link in my `main.c` file but to no avail.

Trying to set

```
#define STM32F4XX
#define USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER
```

in the `main.c` file or defining the symbols `STM32F4XX`, `USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER` in the `Preprocessor` tab in `General Options` as mentioned [here](http://dccharacter.blogspot.de/2013/03/creating-new-project-for-stm32f4.html) also didn't help.

The solution could be very simple that I am probably overlooking but am not able to figure out what could I be missing. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Including a header file in a "project" is not enough, you should actually include it (directly or indirectly) in the source file where the declarations are to be used. It would be that simple in any halfway sane development kit, but we are stuck with ST, and they force us doing it their way.

**Include the "master" header in your `main.c`**

`#include "stm32f429i_discovery.h"`

this would in turn include `stm32f4xx_hal.h`, which includes `stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h`, which included `stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.h` if the right #defines were there.

**You might not have `stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h`**

If that's the case, then copy Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Inc\stm32f4xx_hal_conf_template.h into your project, rename it to `stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h`. Otherwise just make sure that `#define HAL_GPIO_MODULE_ENABLED` is not commented out.

**Set the right #defines**

New versions of STM32CubeF4 have been released since the tutorial you've linked was written, and a few things have apparently changed. As of version 1.6.0, define **`STM32F429xx`** in Preprocessor Options, and forget the ones above. Yes, I've noticed that there is a version 1.7.0 now, let's hope that compatibility lasts this time.